# Generic Method - Can I avoid using reflection in this code?

Tags: c#, generics

Say I have the following method:

```
private static void SetLastModifiedTimeUser<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
{
    PropertyInfo propertyInfo;

    propertyInfo = entity.GetType().GetProperty("LastModifiedUser");
    if (propertyInfo != null)
        propertyInfo.SetValue(entity, IdentityHelper.UserName, null);
}
```

As you can see, the method accepts a generic type. Every class passed to this method will contain a property named 'LastModifiedUser'. Is there a way I can access this property without using reflection? I don't think there is, but I thought I'd ask.

Comment: You could do a series of conditional cast attempts..of course, that'd be slower than reflection :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if all your entities have `LastModifiedUser` property, then you can make all entities inherit from base class, or implement some interface like

```
public interface IModifyable
{
    string LastModifiedUser { get; set; }
}
```

Then just add this constraint (or make your method non-generic, accepting `IModifyable`)

```
where TEntity : class, IModifyable
```

And your code will look like:

```
private static void SetLastModifiedTimeUser<TEntity>(TEntity entity) 
   where TEntity : class, IModifyable
{
   entity.LastModifiedUser = IdentityHelper.UserName;
}
```

Comment: Of course the question is : in that case do you need the generic at all?

Comment: @LaurentBourgault-Roy agree, in this case simple `IModifyable` argument also will do the job. But not always it is possible to just replace generic with interface. E.g. when we create new entities with `new()`. Or when we need strongly-typed class with one concrete type of entities - if I have `Repository<User>`, then I don't want to have non-generic `Repository` which accepts `IModifyable`

Answer (score 3):

Have your class inherit from an interface that defines a `LastModifiedUser` property.

```
public interface ILastModifiedUser
{
    public string LastModifiedUser { get; set; }
}
```

Change your method declaration to

```
private static void SetLastModifiedTimeUser(ILastModifiedUser entity)
```

Comment: Did you mean implement the interface? Just want to get the terminology straight.

Comment: The OP says that the method is already implemented in all of his classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't modify all the classes to implement a common interface you can use `dynamic`

```
private static void SetLastModifiedTimeUser<TEntity>(TEntity entity) where TEntity : class
{
    dynamic d = entity;
    d.LastModifiedUser = IdentityHelper.UserName;
}
```

Otherwise it is as simple as shown by [Robert Harvey](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691050/generic-method-can-i-avoid-using-reflection-in-this-code/13691096#13691096).

Comment: That would probably be worse than using reflection, not better.  At best it's about the same.

Comment: Interesting approach, but not sure I want to use dynamics.

Comment: @Servy just shorter, I didn't say better. Each has its drawbacks.

Answer (score 1):

If you can't add an interface to your objects, consider this approach.

The first time it encounters each Type (TEntity), it looks up the property and gets the property's SetMethod.  Then, on each use, it creates invokes the method.

```
var one = new EntityOne();
LastModifiedTimeUserSetter.Set(one);
Console.WriteLine(one.LastModifiedUser);

public static class LastModifiedTimeUserSetter
{
  public static void Set<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
  {
     var method = Properties.GetOrAdd(typeof (TEntity), GetSetMethod);
     var action = (Action<string>) Delegate.CreateDelegate(typeof (Action<string>), entity, method);
     action(IdentityHelper.UserName);
  }
  static MethodInfo GetSetMethod(Type type)
  {
     var prop = type.GetProperty("LastModifiedUser");
     if (prop == null)
        return null;
     return prop.GetSetMethod();
  }

  static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MethodInfo> Properties = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();
}
```

#### Going further

There is a way to further improve performance by using the [System.Reflection.Emit.MethodBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.methodbuilder.aspx).  And building a method that takes Entity and sets the property.

```
public static class LastModifiedTimeUserSetter
{
  public static void Set<TEntity>(TEntity entity)
  {
     var action = (Action<TEntity>) Properties.GetOrAdd(typeof(TEntity), CreateDynamicSetMethodDelegate);
     if(action != null)
        action(entity);
  }

  static Delegate CreateDynamicSetMethodDelegate(Type type)
  {
     return CreateDynamicSetMethod(type).CreateDelegate(GetActionType(type));
  }

  static DynamicMethod CreateDynamicSetMethod(Type typeWithProperty)
  {
     var methodBuilder = new DynamicMethod(
        "Dynamic_" + typeWithProperty.FullName + "_SetLastModifiedUser",
        typeof (void),
        new[] {typeWithProperty});
     EmitSimpleAssignmentMethod(methodBuilder,
                                GetIdentityHelperUserNameGetMethod(),
                                GetPropertySetMethod(typeWithProperty));
     return methodBuilder;
  }

  static MethodInfo GetIdentityHelperUserNameGetMethod()
  {
     return typeof(IdentityHelper).GetProperty("UserName").GetGetMethod();
  }

  static MethodInfo GetPropertySetMethod(Type type)
  {
     var prop = type.GetProperty("LastModifiedUser");
     if (prop == null)
        return null;
     return prop.GetSetMethod();
  }

  static void EmitSimpleAssignmentMethod(DynamicMethod methodBuilder, MethodInfo getMethod, MethodInfo setMethod)
  {
     var il = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
     il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
     il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, getMethod, null);
     il.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, setMethod, null);
     il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
  }

  static Type GetActionType(Type type)
  {
     return typeof (Action<string>).GetGenericTypeDefinition().MakeGenericType(type);
  }

  static readonly ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Delegate> Properties = new ConcurrentDictionary<Type, Delegate>();
}
```

See an [Article from MSDN magazine about XBOX Live](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163960.aspx).